# Объединить датафреймы pandas без ключа

Tags: python, pandas

Есть два разных датафрейма с разными столбцами. В каждом датафрейме по два столбца.
Хочу их объединить, чтобы в итоговом датафрейме получилось 4 столбца.
Индексы у фреймов разные
Как я могу это сделать?

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: http://espressocode.top/python-merge-join-and-concatenate-dataframes-using-panda/

Answer (score 1):

[pandas.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

```
pd.concat([df1, df1], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Таким образом, добавление происходит, но мне нужно, чтобы итоговый датафрейм не заполнялся NAN. Мне нужно чтобы строка одного датафрейма соответствовала строке другого

Comment: @formanite Что значит "соответствовала" - у вас одинаковое количество строк там хотя бы?

Comment: одинаковое, помогло reset_index. Спасибо)